# Use image as a border CSS3

Tags: html, css

I need to use an image as a border. I have the image but I am unable to successfully achieve the task.
I need to use that border to my complete body.

Have a look at my work:

http://jsfiddle.net/A3MBH/

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px dotted #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.image{
    border-width: 25px;
    -moz-border-image: url("http://s17.postimg.org/aftdxgoxn/border.png") 50 40 repeat repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url("http://s17.postimg.org/aftdxgoxn/border.png") 50 40 repeat repeat;
    border-image: url("http://s17.postimg.org/aftdxgoxn/border.png") 50 40 repeat repeat;    
}
```

I need to look like the above but using the image.
Can someone help?

What do I need? I basically need a round border with a drop shadow effect, I tried searching in google but unable to find any related article.

Is this possible to add a dotted border with some radius and have a shadows? Is it possible in CSS3?
If not then will image work?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: if you want to use border image, you will need a mask to hide the radius wich doesn't apply when border-image is used. This mask can be used to hide corners and dispatch as many multiple background images needed to draw the radius border , see my answer below and example. tune it to your needs and place as many single image to draw corners..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If border-image + a mask doesn't suits you, try with dotted borders sprayed on 2 elements :
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/czKEp

```
html {
  padding:2em 5em;
}
body , div{
  border:dotted 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  height:100%;
  border-radius:5em;  
  margin:0;
}
div {
  margin:-12px;
  border-color:gray;
  min-height:10em;
  padding:2em;
}
```

`<div>dotted radius</div>`

`Border-image` and multiple backgrounds do look much better :)

Comment: this can used as an horrible fallback to rounded border-image :p

Comment: okay, i guess there is no possible way to get that exact look, right? :(

Comment: This looks fine from rest, but position is not perfect.. I guess there is no way to get the exact look?

Comment: exact look can only be achieve with image, dotted borders will show different from browsers to others , it just an average look.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/A3MBH/6/ Or to be exact this: http://jsfiddle.net/A3MBH/7/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image">
     <div class="contentDiv">
        Content goes here.
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image{
   padding: 30px 15px 12px 15px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 310px;    
   background: url("http://s17.postimg.org/aftdxgoxn/border.png") 0 0 repeat transparent ;
}
.contentDiv{
   background:#ffffff;
   width: 280px;
   height: 290px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to use this effect as a border: http://s17.postimg.org/aftdxgoxn/border.png

Comment: Don't use images, that can be created easily with CSS3. You'll run into scaling and browser/device issues and have to do more work than you should.

Comment: @user2485649 This should do it. Check the updated link

Comment: yes, you have got to 90% correct.. Just need to add a radius kind effect.. Like this is what I need: http://s27.postimg.org/p890yp575/border.png
is this possible?

Comment: I don't think that's possible...best thing you can do is use transparent image or without round border's

Comment: @Ani look here using a pseudo element as a mask and still with border-image: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dbHFx/

Comment: @GCyrillus Cool...That should do it for OP. Excellent work right there

Comment: @user2485649 your supposed to see what the screen shot i added in my answer shows , wich browser do you use ? for me : IE11, FF28, Chrome  shows a rounded box aside a squared box

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at

## http://jsfiddle.net/fauverism/A3MBH/5/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<span class="circle-1"></span>
  <span class="circle-2"></span>
  <span class="circle-3"></span>
  <span class="circle-4"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.circle-1 {
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.circle-2 {
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.circle-3 {
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.circle-4 {
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

You can create multiple span.circle s and position the span elements in a container div.

Don't use images, that can be created easily with CSS3. You'll run into scaling and browser/device issues and have to do more work than you should.

Comment: But how will I add this span to body border?

Comment: body radius? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain.. I need same effect which is there in png, and adding that to body tag.
Also need to use border-radius, i.e. round corners

Comment: Sure, sorry about that I wasn't logged into my fiddle account. http://jsfiddle.net/fauverism/A3MBH/5/

Comment: Umm.. but what about the complete border? I need to look like the top  one from here: http://jsfiddle.net/A3MBH/
the below is not correct this is what is the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use border-image, you need to use a proper image in order to draw the borders.
[image: border-image]
and than apply style like this :

```
.image {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  margin:auto;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width: 32px 34px 31px 30px; 
  -moz-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDDO2.png) 32 34 31 30 round; 
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDDO2.png) 32 34 31 30 round; 
  -o-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDDO2.png) 32 34 31 30 round; 
  border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDDO2.png) 32 34 31 30 round;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A3MBH/8/

---

using pseudo element as a mask , you can obtain this result : [image: rounded border image]

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dbHFx/

tune it to your needs :)

---

*In order to use on fluid layout, use 2 pseudo elements , respectively set to top and bottom in absolute position. mask borders and draw round borders frop them according to your radius value*

Comment: Well , -1 for the **use of border-image as asked** ... explain . and here it is even with rounded corner :  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dbHFx/